# How do I keep track of the subcategory I am in using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have seen it many times, but I'm not sure how it is done. I am referring to sites like online catalogues where they have a legend(or a map) to your subcategory.

it looks like: Electronics > Laptops > 15" > Under $500

Can someone tell me what it is called so I can Google it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"Breadcrumb Navigation"+PHP`

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone tell me what it is called so I can Google it?

It is called a [Breadcrumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29)

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is usually referred to as a [breadcrumb trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29).

Answer (score 1):

its commonly referred to as 'breadcrumbs'